# How to change meteor smart package redirect url?

Tags: javascript, localhost, meteor

I have used the built in accounts-facebook smart package with meteor, and would like to know how to change the redirect url from localhost to to some other site.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are looking to do.  Have you configured the accounts-facebook package?  You will likely need to change this within both the config for the package as well as the config on facebook developers console for the app itself.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to change it on Facebook developers page related to your app?

Comment: @jnolte How do I configure the accounts-facebook package? I'm basically trying to run the party example, but with it being publically accessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Shane Chin - Here is what I have in /helpers/config/:

```
// http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_config
    Accounts.ui.config({
      requestPermissions: {
        facebook: ['user_likes']
        // others tbd
      },
        requestOfflineToken:{
          // tbd
        },
        passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_AND_OPTIONAL_EMAIL'  
    });
```

In addition I would take a look at the link for configuring user accounts: http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_config

Once this is setup it should ask you for details to setup the app AppID and Secrect which you can acquire from https://developers.facebook.com once you setup a new app with Facebook.

Comment: I've setup the AppId, Secret w/ Facebook, but I don't have a helpers/config/, I initiated it via the party tutorial application

Comment: After you meteor create --example, the app id/secret are asked for within the online application itself. facebook recognizes the app, but it seems as if the redirect url is hard coded somewhere else.